# Add MS files details property/value using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, file

I need to add a new property/value set to MS files and used following code:

```
$directory = "C:\Your\Directory\Path"
$newTags = @{
    "Tag1" = "Value1"
}
function Add-TagsToFiles {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [hashtable]$tags
    )
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -File
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        foreach ($tag in $tags.GetEnumerator()) {
            $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $tag.Key -Value $tag.Value -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
    }
}
Add-TagsToFiles -path $directory -tags $newTags
Write-Host "New tags and values added to all files under $directory"
```

It does not throw any error but does not add the property/value either.

For e.g. adding a new attrib under file details:

[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wtlD.png)

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Why is there everything twice in your question? What do you mean by "*add a new proverty/value set*" and what are "*MS files*"?

Comment: The code is adding a NoteProperty to the $file variable. Is the goal to add a NoteProperty that will always be present in the System.IO.FileInfo structure of the file?

Comment: I need to create a new property/value set for Microsoft Office files like *.docx.
So, if need to add, say "Project" = "Test" under file properties -> Details -> properties tab.